# rewriterule to mach "foldername" to "00_foldername"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 100 folders each start with a number and underscore like 001_folder1, 002_folder2. 
I wrote 100 lines of rewrite code to match 001_folder1 to folder1 and etc.

```
    RewriteRule ^/?mainFolder\/folder1\/$ mainFolder\/001_folder1/index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?mainFolder\/folder2\/$ mainFolder\/002_folder2/index.php [L]
    .
    .
```

I don't know if its efficient or not, but I need a general rule to match them.

something like:

```
    RewriteRule ^/?mainFolder\/([a-z]*)$ mainFolder\/[(0-9){3}_$1 [NC,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **single rule to replae your 100 rules**:

```
RewriteRule ^/?mainFolder/folder(1)/$ /mainFolder/00$1_folder$1/index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's not that simple, the 3 digit number before the "_" has nothing to do with the folder name. better example : 001_folderX, 002_folderABC, etc